Can I use NM cable to connect a timer in this application?
I need to connect a timer (Intermatic T104R) to a pool pump so I don’t have to run it all the time. I have a similar setup for our fountain and I basically want to replicate this on a separate panel. In that application (photo) the electrician  made the connection from the panel to the timer using NM.
For my spa, the panel is mounted on cement block instead of wood, and all the connections coming in and out are either flexible or solid PVC. There aren’t too many openings left at the bottom so space is getting tight. There is a large knockout on the side of the panel, but (1 inch and 1 ½ inch?) but it’s one of those two size knockouts that I always find difficult to just pop the smaller one. That knockout is also right next to the grounding lug, and I’m afraid to mess around that area.
The timer will be located just left of the panel.
Question 1: Can I use NM cable without any conduit/PVC to connect the timer with the panel like in the other application? (One 12 gauge line in, one out, with ground). That would be so much easier. If so, do I need to do anything specific to support the NM, like attaching a board to the block and then clamping the NM to the board? If it matters, the total length of the NM will be about 12 inches if I use a bottom knockout, and even shorter if I use that side knockout.
Question 2: If I need to protect the NM cable, can I run Romex through flexible conduit? Is it correct that that I would need separate ½ inch conduits for each wire?
Question 3: If I can’t use NM cable, what’s the easiest way to connect? THHN through flexible PVC?



None of the above.
You could probably get away with NM cable, unless this is determined to be a wet location. Support wouldn't be an issue because it is so short and providing physical protection also not likely an issue even if it may be technically required.
You could certainly use PVC with individual wires.
But why not use a rigid metal conduit nipple? It will connect to knockouts on both the panel and the timer box. It can easily handle both the "in" and "out" wires. Plus you don't need to run a ground wire between the panel and the timer. And metal + metal + metal just seems more rugged to me than metal + plastic + metal.
Looking at the T104 specs, it looks like it has combination 1/2" - 3/4" knockouts on the bottom and the back. Which means using a 90 degree elbow like this one from Home Depot plus, if you really only have large knockouts on the panel, a reducing bushing or similar part to adapt the different sizes. The key is to piece it all together before mounting the timer box on the wall so that you know exactly where to mount it.

Thanks. I'll see if the rigid pipe will put the timer in a position I can reach. Appreciate the tip on piecing it together before.
